# How to generate an AuthenticationMD5Password message

Tags: postgresql, protocols, libpq

I'm creating a postgresql client in gdscript (you can answer my question even if you don't know how to code in gdscript).

To do this I use the postgresql protocol [specification](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-flow.html)

I managed to contact the server and it asks me for "AuthenticationMD5Password", but I cannot identify myself. I followed the procedure to generate the password described on the page but I get a server error.

with this sql formula that I adapted in gdscript:

```
concat('md5', md5(concat(md5(concat(password, username)), random-salt)))
```

With "password" the value "test", "username" the value "test" and "random-salt" the value "98dec364".

We obtain: md5936597c6b72ab2681ca01dca38b17da0

I get the following error: Message: password authentication failed for user "test"
SQLSTATE code: 28P01

It seems to come from salt, is the format really an exadecimal string? I tried translating it to utf8 but it doesn't work, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The salt is not 8 hexadecimal digits, it is 4 bytes.  They are just binary bytes, so they don't have a character set.

Comment: yes but it is the same the bytes can have a value between 0 and 255 or between 00 and ff. what i do is just take that hex value and turn it into a string. this is what is in the frame sent by the server. but i dont know if the salt should actually be a hex string or utf8, either way it doesn't work.

Comment: Should bytes be considered a number, a utf8 string, a binnar character string (10010110 ...) ,or just a hexadecimal chiane? 
Knowing that the md5 function accepts only one character string as parameter.

Comment: From the md5 hash you report, you are treating the salt as 8 bytes which just happen to be in the range of 0-9 and a-f.  You aren't treating them like the 4 bytes they represent.  What the server sends you is 4 bytes, not 8 bytes from a restricted range. You don't need to translate them to anything, you need to *not* translate them. This seems like a question about gdscript programming, which I probably can't help with.

Comment: ok, but suddenly how could I define the salt when the md5 function takes a string as parameter or more simply how to concatenate a string with bytes? gdscript is very close to python language, can you give me an example in python? 
(sorry for all i ask)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-message-types.html According to this page, documentation bytes should be seen as characters, but I can't connect when translating to utf8 because bytes -> utf8 conversion doesn't work. I tested with ascii and got unprintable characters like salt. This results in a server error, the same as defined in my post.

Comment: in fact I succeeded that's what you said, excuse my unbearable ignorance, thank you!